# Unknown provider: $httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider <- $httpParamSerializerJQLike

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason this error is happening to me and I don't know why. I am using this so I don't get a CORS issue.

This is the full error I get. Does anyone now why this would be happening?

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider <- $httpParamSerializerJQLike
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider%20%3C-%20%24httpParamSerializerJQLike

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $http, $q, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(e, from, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        $http({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/session',
          method: 'POST',
          data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({token:localStorage['access_token']}),
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        .success(function(resp) {

        })
        .error(function(){ 

        });


    });


})
```

Comment: I don't think httpParamSerializerJQLike is available in 1.3.14

Comment: @AnthonyC correct, it wasn't there ver. 1.3.14, this has been introduced in [rc.1.4.0.rc-2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-rc2-rocket-zambonimation-2015-05-12)

Comment: @AnthonyC Thank you both. I tried 1.5.10 and it worked nicely. Still getting `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` but that is another question all together.